# How to make json array parsing work on the server side

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have an action on my server side:

```
public void Action(Container container)
{
}
```

where container is:

```
public class Container
{
   public string[] Arr;
}
```

From the client side, I'm invoking this action in the way below:

```
$.post("Controller/Action", { Arr: "abc" }, null, "json");
```

After this, the **Arr** in container contains one element "**abc**".

But, while invoking action the way below:

```
$.post("Controller/Action", { Arr: ["abc", "def"] }, null, "json");
```

the json array is not deserializing on the server side. The **Arr** in container is **NULL**.

How to make this simple thing work ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using jquery 1.4 try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'Controller/Action',
    type: 'post',
    data: { Arr: [ 'abc', 'def' ] },
    traditional: true,
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

Notice the [`traditional` flag](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Or if you prefer to continue using [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/):

```
$.post(
    'Controller/Action', 
    $.param({ Arr: [ 'abc', 'def'] }, true), 
    null, 
    'json'
);
```